# The substitution $y = ix$

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration

Given $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx$, under what conditions would the substitution $y = ix$ not change the limits of integration, so to speak? Since setting $y = ix$ changes the range of integration to a path in the complex plane, we could choose some contour $C$ that includes the positive real axis and show, if possible, that $\oint_C f(z) dz = \int_0^\infty f(x) dx$. The question is: When does this happen? What conditions must $f$ satisfy for this to occur, that is, when would the limits of integration remain unchanged? In other words, when would $\int_0^\infty f(x) dx = -i\int_0^\infty f(-iy) dy$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What conditions must $f$ satisfy for this to occur for some contour $C$
$$\quad$$
or
$$\quad$$
given a counter $C$, what conditions must $f$ satisfy for this to occur?

Comment: The way your question is phrased, it sounds like you want a necessary condition for this to happen. I have no difficulty thinking of *sufficient* conditions; finding necessary conditions seem much harder.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen Indeed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One fairly simple case where this would happen, is this: For $R>0$, let $C_R$ be the curve along the real axis from $0$ to $R$, followed by the quarter circle of radius $R$ in the fourth quadrant ending at $-iR$, and back along the imaginary axis to $0$. If $f$ is analytic in the fourth quadrant, then $\oint_{C_R}f(z)\,dz=0$. Therefore, if the contribution from the quarter circle vanishes in the limit when $R\to\infty$, then $\int_0^\infty f(x)\,dx=-i\int_0^\infty f(-iy)\,dy$ – in the sense that if either limit exists, then so does the other, and the two integrals agree.

With $\Gamma_R$ being just the quarter circle mentioned above, there are various ways to ensure $\lim_{R\to\infty}\int_{\Gamma_R}f(z)\,dz=0$. The simplest is if $f$ satisfies $\lvert f(z)\rvert=o(\lvert z\rvert^{-1})$ in the fourth quadrant, but this is not at all necessary.

For example, consider $f(z)=e^{-iz}/z$. Then $\lvert f(z)\rvert=e^y/\lvert z\rvert$ (with $y=\operatorname{Im}(z)$). You can easily get the required estimates on the integral; it is somewhat easier to replace $\Gamma_R$ with two sides of a square, using $e^y/\lvert z\rvert\le e^y/\lvert y\rvert$ along one side and $e^y/\lvert z\rvert\le e^y/\lvert x\rvert$ along the other.

Comment: The lack of any answers so far makes me suspect that people think you expect a more sophisticated answer than the above, and so not answering because they are unsure what you expect. So I am throwing this answer in there, with the risk that it is far simpler than what you have in mind. If so, please rephrase your question so we can understand your need a little better.

Comment: Great answer. It makes sense. Essentially, the problem reduces to finding conditions under which the contribution from $\Gamma_R$ vanishes.

Comment: Dear Harald, In the last line of your answer, should the inequalities be reversed?  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Indeed. Fixed.